# How to keep on execute a function implicitly in PHP at certain time interval like setTimeout() function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, function, cron, settimeout

I've following JavaScript code :

```
setTimeout('$.ajaxCall("notification.update", "", "GET");', 1000);
```

Now I want to execute the following function statement at a fix time interval of 1000 like above javascript code.

```
$notifications = Phpfox::massCallback('getGlobalNotifications');
```

The statement `Phpfox::massCallback('getGlobalNotifications');` should get call at fix time interval of **1000** and the returned result should be updated in `$notifications` table.

If you have any doubt regarding the issue I'm facing please do let me know.

Thanks in advance.

How should I do this in an reliable, efficient and optimum way in PHP?

There is Linux operating system running on a server.

Answer (score 0):

```
function settitle() 
{
    $("#notifyno").load('notifytitle.php'); // your page link goes here

    setTimeout("settitle()", 60000);
}
```

Comment: Please explain what this does for the OP